# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow question (using to publish text in various SQL Data Bases), is possible?

Tags: workflow, sql

First Question:

1. I Need Create one workflow to publish news, and other texts in other SQL. Is it possible?
   The workflow is:

   - Step One: The Writer send the text with the sharepoint blog (for example)
   - Step Two: The workflow send the text to SQL data base of Homologation Base of other site NON Sharepoint (Web site in ASP Net MVC 4)
   - Step Three: the Homologation Man read the notice and give the OK
   - Step Four: the Publisher give the Ok on Sharepoint
   - Step Five: Sharepoint Workflow send the texto to SQL of production Base (of the same site non sharepoint)
2. If it is possible, how can it be done?

---

Edit:
@Robert Kaucher;

I do'nt know how to send you an e - mail Robert , but I really need your help .

Anyway I will already say here in more detail what I need :

The Enterprise Portal ( www.cabesp.com.br ) has 3 different databases :
1 - Development
2 - Approval
3 - Production

I have the password of the three databases .

The news is applied to the base table called news and the news banner on another table called banner .

I need to open the Workflow Editor ( intranet ) write the news and make a banner and go via workflow / sharepoint 2013.
Click to send the news is saved on the basis of development and approval .
So the countersigning that is a different person on each news should hokmologar and give the OK or NO .

If given the OK workflow must send a notice to the publisher (which is always the same user as well as the editor ) , so that it gives OK and other news is published in the database of production and so Cabesp Portal be public.

The portal is made ​​in AspNet MVC 4 ( C # ) using visual studio 2010 and Entity Framework .

I prefer to make the workflow and workflow management using the Sharepoint Designer (if faster that way , of course )

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível, sim.

1. O workflow deve iniciar quando um novo documento está criado e então pode escrever as informações necessárias ao base de dados usando Entity Framework. Ou se o site utiliza Web API, o workflow pode criar assim.
2. No site MVC o responsável pode autorizar o documento e o sistema pode usar o client side object model para atualizar um campo no documento em SharePoint.
3. O workflow perceberá a atualização e então notificará a pessoa responsável para a publicação do texto.
4. Quando o text seja autorizado, o workflow pode publicar o texto oficialmente no outro site.

Você pode usar SharePoint Designer ou Visual Studio para criar o workflow em SharePoint. Mas sem informações específicas sobre o site MVC é difícil dar instruções mais concretas. Pode entrar em contato comigo pelo email se quiser.

It is possible.

Before you get started. You have to decide how SharePoint will be accessing the databases. If you are [using Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671.aspx), you might want to add the SQL table as an [external content type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220063.aspx) so that the workflow can write to the database because SharePoint Designer workflows do not have a  built in way to perform operations on a SQL database.

1. The workflow should start when a new document is created and can write the necessary information to the database using Entity Framework. If the MVC site uses Web API, the workflow could write to the database using an HTTP POST. If using Designer, you could add an item to the external list (see image).

[image: Make sure it starts when an item is created and when an item is updated.]

[image: Pick the method to use.]

2. The person responsible for approval in the MVC site will make their approval and the MVC system can use the [Client Side Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193041.aspx) to update a field on the document in SharePoint. Or you could use the [Workflow Client API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn481315.aspx). This really depends on what you feel comfortable with as this needs to be done on the MVC site.
3. The workflow will perceive the change in the SharePoint document and notify the person responsible for publishing the document or text. This will be a [SharePoint approval workflow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/16/a-sample-approval-workflow-which-can-be-recalled-by-initiator.aspx).
4. Once the text is approved the worklow can then publish the text officially in the MVC site. This will be similar to the first step and depends on how the MVC site functions internally.

You can use SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio to create the workflow in SharePoint. Without more specific information about the MVC site it's hard to give you more concrete steps. Feel free to contact me via email if you would like.

Comment: What's up with the French? ;)

Comment: Lol, I just happen to speak Portuguese and noticed the OP was from Brazil.

Comment: Haha nice catch!

Comment: Robert, Thank you so much and thank you to speak to me in portuguese! haha. I will need more help. how can i send to you one email?

Comment: Robert, i edited the topic with more infos of my problem. Thank You.

Comment: Robert, Thank you, now you can delete your commnet, i have your email! thank you so much